# Mule Implementing API gateway

Tags: cloud, mule, esb, mule-component

Hi am running an application

> example.cloudhub.io

on cloud hub now i created an API and gave implementation URI as

> example.cloudhub.io

now how can i hit the cloud API gateway using soap UI

What will be the URL for this API gateway where can i find it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a inbound http endpoint in your application with address: "http://localhost:8081/order", then the CH URL is: "http://example.cloudhub.io/order"

HTH

Comment: Hi you are saying to hit the application directly but i want it to go through the API i have created. http://example.cloudhub.io/mypath is the application path but in cloudhub i created an API named proxy now i have to go through this API

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, this should be the value of the "baseUri" entry in your RAML file.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a http/https inbound-endpoint within your app. Then the URL would be a concatenation of the scheme your using(http/https) plus the domain(example.cloudhub.io) plus the path in your endpoint path attribute or address attribute.

so:

```
<http:inbound:endpoint host="localhost" port=${http.port} path="/mypath" >
```

would be

http://example.cloudhub.io/mypath

**Note** use ${http.port} and ${https.port} respectively, these automatically get assigned to 80 and 443 and Cloudhub only supports incoming traffic on these ports.

http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Developing+a+CloudHub+Application

Comment: Hi you are saying to hit the application directly but i want it to go through the API i have created. http://example.cloudhub.io/mypath is the application path but in cloudhub i created an API named proxy now i have to go through this API